# Error on image upload for IBM Mobile Application Builder custom data source - Android

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

Android application developed with **IBMs Mobile App Developer** from Bluemix.

Images don't upload for user created `Cloud` data-sources.

The errors reported when attempting to upload are as follows:

1. from the AppBuilder interface

   > "There was an error uploading the file. Please try again later."
2. from the Android app

   > Network error

p.s. Images successfully upload when using the provided template data-sources.

UPDATE 1

The data source includes a column named "id" of type `int`

Comment: I just made a `Cloud` datasource and uploaded an image with no problems. Could you take a screenshot of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reason for your error was caused by a temporary network issue. I was able to upload data to a `Cloud` datasource without any problems. If it reoccurs, please update this question.

Comment: The upload is still not working from the DEV web client (PC - Chrome and FireFox), although the error message has changed to **There was an error uploading the file. Please try again later** from the error after yesterday's attempt.

Comment: Note that the image view updates in the dialog box for the template data source but not at all for a new user defined CLOUD type

Comment: Feedback: If the data source does not have an "id" field defined then the upload works